# changing column to data

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a database:

```
   Date          14/06/2019
0  08/06/2019    some data
1  07/06/2019    some data
2  08/06/2019    NaN
3  06/06/2019    NaN
```

And I want the output as:

```
Date
0  14/06/2019
1  14/06/2019
2  08/06/2019
3  06/06/2019
```

Means, I want to delete the "14/06/2019" column and overwrite the rows of "Date" column where the rows of "14/06/2019" have some data and leave the rows of "Date" column as it is where rows of "14/06/2019" is NaN.

Comment: Please share something that you've tried so fat.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for extract column `14/06/2019`, test for missing values by [`Series.notna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) and overwrite values if condition match by [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[df.pop('14/06/2019').notna(), 'Date'] = "14/06/2019"
```

Or [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html):

```
df['Date'] = df['Date'].where(df.pop('14/06/2019').isna(), "14/06/2019")
#alternative with mask and notna
#df['Date'] = df['Date'].mask(df.pop('14/06/2019').notna(), "14/06/2019")
```

Or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Date'] = np.where(df.pop('14/06/2019').notna(), "14/06/2019", df['Date'])

print (df)
         Date
0  14/06/2019
1  14/06/2019
2  08/06/2019
3  06/06/2019
```

Comment: your 2nd solution is working fine, but 1st and 3rd give the following output:            
              Date
0  08/06/2019
1  07/06/2019
2  14/06/2019
3  14/06/2019